# Unable to execute cloned GitHub repositories due to failed Python imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, path

I successfully clone a GitHub repository (the cloned files match that of the repository exactly). I then attempt to run a downloaded example file which fails because modules from that repository can't be found. This occurs no matter what directory I run the file from. I can't believe that I have to modify the sys.path file for every GitHub cloning. This has happened with multiple different repositories.

A specific example:

I clone the Pytorch-NEAT repository and get this directory:

```
examples    Initial Commit  10 months ago
pytorch_neat    Initial Commit  10 months ago
tests   Initial Commit  10 months ago
LICENSE Initial Commit  10 months ago
README.md   Added links 10 months ago
requirements.txt    Initial Commit  10 months ago
```

The directory "examples" includes the directory "simple" which includes the file main.py. I run main.py either in Terminal or IDLE, both of which fail.

main.py includes this code:

```
import os
import click
import gym
import neat
from pytorch_neat.multi_env_eval import MultiEnvEvaluator
```

The first 4 import statements succeed. The 5th fails with the message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "PyTorch-NEAT/examples/simple/main.py", line 23, in 
      from pytorch_neat.multi_env_eval import MultiEnvEvaluator
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytorch_neat'

Obviously, there is a module pytorch-neat in PyTorch-NEAT.

If I print sys.path prior to the failure, it is this:

Garys-MacBook-Air-5:simple garyblauer$ python3 main.py
['/Users/garyblauer/ne/PyTorch-NEAT/examples/simple', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages']

The first line differs, of course, depending on which directory I run from but the rest is always the same and it always fails.

I think there needs to be something in sys.path telling the interpreter to look in the PyTorch-NEAT directory or something like that but I don't know how to add this and just can't believe this is necessary every time I clone a repository.

I must be missing something simple.

Comment: Where are you running the file from (and how)?

Comment: Have you checked your [PYTHONPATH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250929/pythonpath-environment-variable)?

Comment: Running in Mac Terminal. Navigate to a directory in the cloned repository and then run the script. I've tried from all of the directories in the clone. So it looks like PYTHONPATH is the answer. Thank you. I will study it. Is it necessary to create a PYTHONPATH for every clone from GitHub? It never mentioned in the README discussions of how to use a repository.

Comment: @gblauer hey there, when you reply to a comment, remember to @ the person you are replying to, otherwise there won't be any notification. Going back to your question, PYTHONPATH is just an environment variable, whenever you want to `import` your local packages, you need to update this variable. There should be only one PYTHONPATH and you just append to this whenever you start on a new project.

Comment: @UdonN00dle thanks for the "@" tip. obviously I'm a stackoverflow rookie. I sort of have things working now by using sys.append.path(...). The documentation I've found so far for accessing PYTHONPATH directly is confusing. Is the sys.path approach a problem?

Comment: @gblauer I do see a small issue with `sys.path`, that is if you leave this piece in your code, it will append to PYTHONPATH every time you run your program, which means you'll have multiple entries with the same value. You are on a Mac, so it should be configured in the `.bash_profile` file, see [this link](https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/using_pythonpath.html#if-you-are-on-a-mac) for more.